# When I click the submit button, it doesn't store to the database, but it keeps redirecting back to the form page

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios, formik

I'm using Reactjs and Material UI and then Formik for the form validation. Whenever I finish completing the form and then hit the submit button, it looks as if it's making the request to post the data to the back-end, but then it reload back to the same form page.

```
        const initialValues = {
          from: "",
          to: "",
          purpose: "",
          date: "",
          kilometer: "",
          amount: "",
          claimType: "",
          fullname:"",
          vehicleNo: "",
          bank: "",
          email: "",
          department: "",
          status:"",
        };
        useEffect(() => {
          if(!localStorage.getItem("accessToken")){
            history.push("/");
          }
        }, [])
        const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
          from: Yup.string().required(),
          to: Yup.string().required() ,
          purpose:Yup.string().required(),
          date:Yup.date().required(),
          kilometer:Yup.number().required(),
          amount: Yup.number().required(),
          claimType: Yup.string().required(),
          fullname: Yup.string().required(),
          vehicleNo: Yup.string().required(),
          department: Yup.string().required(),
          bank: Yup.string().required(),    
          email: Yup.string().email(),
          status: Yup.string(),
    
    
        });
    
        const onSubmit = (data)=> {
          axios
          .post("http://localhost:5001/dutyMileage",  data, {
            headers: 
            { accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken")},
          })
          .then((response) => {
              console.log("it worked");
              history.push('/Home');
              
          })
        }
     

return ( 
<div>

    <Formik 
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema} >

    <form className={classes.root}  onSubmit={() => { alert("Claim Submitted"); }}>
       <div className="formstep1">
         <div>
        <TextField 
        label="Full Name"
         required
        autoComplete="off"
        variant="outlined"
        name="fullname"  
        placeholder="Enter your Full name"
        />
    

    <TextField 
                    label="Department"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="department" 
                    placeholder="Enter your department"
                    />
                    </div>
    
                    <div>
                    <TextField 
                    label="Bank"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="bank" 
                    placeholder="Enter your bank name"
                    />
                   <TextField
                    label="Date"
                    name="date"
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                    </div>
    
                    <div>
           
                   <TextField 
                     disabled
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="status"
                    name="status"
                    value="PENDING"
                    />
    
                  <TextField 
                    label="Email"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="email" 
                    placeholder="Enter your Email "
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="select">
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Claim Type</InputLabel>
            <Select
             required
             name="claimType"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Claim Type"
              value={claimType}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value="Duty Mileage">Duty Mileage</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Travelling Allowances">Travelling Allowances</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Approved Purchases">Approved Purchases</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Guest Of University">Guest Of University </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Other Claims">Other Claims</MenuItem>
              
            </Select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
    
                    <TextField
              label="Kilometer"
              name="kilometer"
              className={classes.root, classes.textField}
              InputProps={{
                endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">Km</InputAdornment>,
              }}
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={ (event) => {
                setKilometer(event.target.value);
              }}
              placeholder="Number of Kilometers"
            />
             <TextField
            label="Amount"
            onChange={handleChangee}
            name="amount"
            InputProps={{
              inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
            }}
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="Enter Amount In Naira"
          />
          </div>
    
          <div>
                    <TextField 
                    label="From"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    placeholder="Journey From"
                    name="from" />
    
                    <TextField 
                    label="To"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="to" 
                    placeholder="journey To"
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <TextField 
                    label="Vehicle Number"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="vehicleNo" 
                    placeholder="Enter your Vehicle Number"
                    />
                    <TextField 
                    label="Purpose"
                     required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="purpose" 
                    placeholder="purpose"
                    />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit"> Submit Claim</button>
                </form>
                </Formik>
                
                  </Paper>
        </div> 
    
        
            ); 
        }
```

And the back end goes like this

The router request:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { DutyMileage } = require("../models");
const { validateToken } = require("../middlewares/AuthMiddleware");


router.post("/", validateToken, async(req, res) => {
    const post = req.body;
    post.userId = req.username.userId;
    post.StaffId = req.username.id;
   await DutyMileage.create(post);
   res.json(post);
    
});
```

Anytime I make request to submit the data to the database, it keeps reloading and it's stuck on the form page.

Comment: Any help will go along way guys

Comment: What does your backend say?

Comment: Nothing .....no error ....nothing shows

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have errors in console, check inspection in browser and your node(npm console) errors

Second, here is code from formik official lib, try to remake you template for this to test:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{yourInitialValues}}
        validationSchema={yourYupValidation}
        onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting, resetForm}) => {
            // When button submits form and form is in the process of submitting, submit button is disabled
            setSubmitting(true);
            // Simulate submitting to database, shows us values submitted, resets form
            setTimeout(() => {

                //your code to send to API
                //you can debug and test values here
                alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
                setSubmitting(false);
            }, 1);
        }}
      >
{( {values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleReset,
    setFieldValue, 
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldTouched,
    isSubmitting }) => (
    //use only formik functions to test
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    
    </form>

)}
</Formik>
```

And last one: you have `onSubmit={() => { alert("Claim Submitted"); }}`, just check this line, you just console log `onSubmit`. Also your onSubmit const is outside Formik component, it may affect formik behaviour.